# How to merge two lists into dictionary without using nested for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .... 99999]
b = [24, 53, 88, 32, 45, 24, 88, 53, ...... 1]
```

I want to merge those two lists into a dictionary like:

```
{
    0: [24, 53, 88], 
    1: [32, 45, 24, 88, 53], 
    ...... 
    99999: [1]
}
```

A solution might be using `for` loop, which does not look good and elegant, like:

```
d = {}
unique_a = list(set(list_a))
for i in range(len(list_a)):
    if list_a[i] in d.keys:
        d[list_a[i]].append(list_b[i])
    else:
        d[list_a] = [list_b[i]]
```

Though this does work, it’s an inefficient and would take too much time when the list is extremely large. I want to know more elegant ways to construct such a dictionary?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is that a nested for loop?

Comment: DYM `if list_a[i] in d.keys` and `d[list_a[i]] = [list_b[i]]`?  Please post *exactly* the code you've tried, preferably using copy+paste (if available on your platform).

Comment: If one of the provided answers worked for you, please mark it as accepted. It makes it easier for people coming across your question in the future to know what worked.

Comment: @TobySpeight `if` means if `list_a[i]` is already a key in the dictionary, then add `list_b[i]` into the dictionary under key `list_a[i]`, whereas `else` means that if not, add `list_b[i] to the new key `list_a[i]` as list. Hope it helps.

Comment: @BigD, I thought that's what you meant to write (as I suggested).  `list_[a] in d.keys` just doesn't make sense, and neither does `d[list_a] =`.  I suggest you [edit] to fix those errors.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
list_a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9999]
list_b = [24, 53, 88, 32, 45, 24, 88, 53, 1]
for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
   d[a].append(b)

print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{0: [24, 53, 88], 1: [32, 45, 24, 88, 53], 9999: [1]}
```

Comment: Really, using a `defaultdict` is overkill here. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055899/4909087) where `dict.setdefault` can handle the same thing with minimal overhead.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `d[a].append(b)` is much cleaner than `d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)`

Comment: At the cost of an extra import and a heavier structure ;-)

Answer (score 14):

Alternative [**`itertools.groupby()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) solution:

```
import itertools

a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
b = [24, 53, 88, 32, 45, 24, 88, 53, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]

result = { k: [i[1] for i in g] 
           for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(zip(a, b)), key=lambda x:x[0]) }
print(result)
```

The output:

```
{0: [24, 53, 88], 1: [24, 32, 45, 53, 88], 2: [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66], 3: [77]}
```

Comment: Sure, I’ve figured out what your code does, but written in that style, it’s not very obvious. For the person new to Python, I think they may find your code hard to understand and then disregard (or not bother to regard) your solution because of it. Just a suggestion, up to you

Comment: Might I suggest not writing `result` in one line? Maybe pull out the result of `groupby` as a separate variable? That line is way too long...

Comment: This seems worse than the other answer because you need to sort, whereas the other answer does not sort, so yours is doing extra work.

Comment: @Daenyth, your information is not new at all. The solution was marked as "alternative" way at the very begining.

Comment: If `list_a` is already ordered, you can remove the `n log n` sort, also the  lambda adds unnecessary overhead, itemgetter is always a better option. `{k: [i for _, i in g] for k, g in groupby(zip(a, b), key=itemgetter(0))}`

Answer (score 6):

No fancy structures, just a plain ol' dictionary.

```
d = {}
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a dict comprehension:

```
list_a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
list_b = [24, 53, 88, 32, 45, 24, 88, 53]
my_dict = {key: [] for key in set(a)}  # my_dict = {0: [], 1: []}
for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    my_dict[a].append(b)
# {0: [24, 53, 88], 1: [32, 45, 24, 88, 53]}
```

Oddly enough, you cannot seem to make this work using `dict.fromkeys(set(list_a), [])` as this will set the value of all keys equal to the *same* empty array:

```
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(set(list_a), [])  # my_dict = {0: [], 1: []}
my_dict[0].append(1)  # my_dict = {0: [1], 1: [1]}
```

Comment: lists are mutable, you pass one object/list to fromkeys so you share a reference to the single list/object, it would be the same as `a = []` then `d = {1: a, 2: a, 3: a}`.  `my_dict = dict.fromkeys(set(list_a), tuple());my_dict[0] += (1,) ` would show `{0: (1,), 1: (), 9999: ()}` but add the overhead of creating a new object/tuple with each `+=`.

Answer (score 3):

A `pandas` solution:

#### Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]

b = pd.np.random.randint(0, 100, len(a)).tolist()

>>> b
Out[]: [28, 68, 71, 25, 25, 79, 30, 50, 17, 1, 35, 23, 52, 87, 21]


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Group', 'Value'], data=list(zip(a, b)))  # Create a dataframe

>>> df
Out[]:
    Group  Value
0       0     28
1       0     68
2       0     71
3       1     25
4       1     25
5       1     79
6       1     30
7       1     50
8       2     17
9       2      1
10      2     35
11      3     23
12      4     52
13      4     87
14      4     21
```

#### Solution:

```
>>> df.groupby('Group').Value.apply(list).to_dict()
Out[]:
{0: [28, 68, 71],
 1: [25, 25, 79, 30, 50],
 2: [17, 1, 35],
 3: [23],
 4: [52, 87, 21]}
```

#### Walkthrough:

1. create a `pd.DataFrame` from the input lists, `a` is called `Group` and `b` called `Value`
2. `df.groupby('Group')` creates groups based on `a`
3. `.Value.apply(list)` gets the values for each group and cast it to `list`
4. `.to_dict()` converts the resulting `DataFrame` to `dict`

#### Timing:

To get an idea of timings for a test set of 1,000,000 values in 100,000 groups:

```
a = sorted(np.random.randint(0, 100000, 1000000).tolist())
b = pd.np.random.randint(0, 100, len(a)).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Group', 'Value'], data=list(zip(a, b)))

>>> df.shape
Out[]: (1000000, 2)

%timeit df.groupby('Group').Value.apply(list).to_dict()
4.13 s ± 9.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But to be honest it is likely less efficient than `itertools.groupby` suggested by @RomanPerekhrest, or `defaultdict` suggested by @Ajax1234.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I miss the point, but at least I will try to help. If you have to lists and want to put them in the dict do the following

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
lists = [a, b] # or directly -> lists = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8] ]
new_dict = {}
for idx, sublist in enumerate([a, b]): # or enumerate(lists)
    new_dict[idx] = sublist
```

hope it helps

Comment: This isn't even close to what OP wants.  `a` contains the keys for the values in `b` (with some keys being duplicates), and index isn't used at all.  Yours just creates `{ 0: a, 1: b }`, using the index in `lists`.

Answer (score 0):

Or do dictionary comprehension beforehand, then since all keys are there with values of empty lists, iterate trough the `zip` of the two lists, then add the second list's value to the dictionary's key naming first list's value, no need for try-except clause (or if statements), to see if the key exists or not, because of the beforehand dictionary comprehension:

```
d={k:[] for k in l}
for x,y in zip(l,l2):
   d[x].append(y)
```

Now:

```
print(d)
```

Is:

```
{0: [24, 53, 88], 1: [32, 45, 24, 88, 53], 9999: [1]}
```